# How to do different things in one procedure depends on event

Tags: c#, delphi, events, event-handling

Good day.

We have 3 buttons, 3 edits and 3 checkboxes. When the button is pressed, the text of corresponding edit should become "10", "20" or "30" and checkbox should become checked:

[image]

How to do it by creating one procedure rather than three? C# or/and Delphi (I think approach must be the same). The problem looks like simple, but I can't get the idea.

Comment: Which language are you actually programming in? Show code

Comment: There is no code, I just yet put controls on the form! I started in Delphi, then I tried in C#, but there, too, could not come up. It does not matter for me, actually. I can create 3 procedures (one for each button), but I need only one, as I have said.

Comment: Create a button groupid indexed

Comment: Use one common event handler and switch behaviour based on the button that was pressed

Comment: @Drew Pierce I don't understand properly, do you mean groupboxes or array or somethng else?

Comment: Better yet consider that no serious GUI would do this as it is dorky

Comment: @David Heffernan Switch on button's name and use different controls names in each branch, clear. May be more compact and universal way?

Comment: No. Don't use names. Use the approach in the answers.

Comment: Are your text boxes enabled?

Comment: @TLama Your approach improves the ones in the answers, right? Can you write some code using them, please?

Comment: What is the point of the button filling in a value, doing the checkbox, and allowing the user to change a value that a click again would overwrite? This looks pretty bad

Comment: There are standards in GUI design. This is not one of them.

Comment: @AsConfused Asker is just using theseee controls as a means to illustrate the question. Which is how to use a single event handler to perform actions on grouped controls. The actions and the controls are not relevant. Try to see past the example to the **concept**.

Comment: @AsConfused Oh, of course, it does not exactly application that I want create. This example contains only the details with which I have a problems.

Comment: Keep us posted on the final screen this i gotta see ;)

Comment: @AsConfused I conceived a great project that illustrates many important things in programming. I will put it on GitHub, but probably I will not finish soon :) Subscribe on my GitHub in profile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a single event handler and find which component fired the event. In Delphi:

```
procedure TForm1.ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Sender = Button1 then
    // react to Button1 being pressed
  else if Sender = Button2 then 
    // react to Button2 being pressed
  // etc. 
end;
```

In C#, for both WinForms and WPF, the sender is also passed to the event handler. For instance:

```
// WPF example
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender == button1)
      // and so on just as above
}
```

And

```
// WinForms
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender == button1)
      // and so on just as above
}
```

Of course all these if statements get pretty clunky. So you might declare a structure that contains the related edit controls. In Delphi

```
type
  TControlGroup = record
    Button: TButton;
    Edit: TEdit;
    CheckBox: TCheckBox;
    DefaultEditText: string;
  end;
```

Define an array of these, or perhaps a dictionary. Populate the container when the form is built. Then add a method to look up the structure from a button instance. This then allows you to paramterise your GUI code to avoid duplication.

Your handler might then look like this:

```
InitialiseGroup(FindGroup(Sender as TButton));
....
procedure TForm1.InitialiseGroup(const Group: TControlGroup);
begin
  Group.Edit.Text := Group.DefaultEditText;
  Group.CheckBox.Checked := True;
end;
```

Obviously you need to fill in the implementation of `FindGroup` to fit with whichever container you decided to use.

Comment: Oh, thanks! This example and description is sufficient, I can write the rest code

Comment: I've fleshed it out a bit more. I hope the rest is clear.

Answer (score 3):

Use one common event handler to find out which button was pressed and set the properties accordingly:

```
procedure TForm1.ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (Sender = Button1) then
  begin
    Edit1.Text := '10';
    Check1.Checked := True;
  end
  else
  if (Sender = Button2) then
  begin
    Edit2.Text := '20';
    Check2.Checked := True;
  end
  else
  if (Sender = Button3) then
  begin
    Edit3.Text := '30';
    Check3.Checked := True;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Are the textboxes disabled?

Comment: By default, the Edit components are enabled.

Answer (score 1):

You can receive the caller in your event handler. The sender object will hold the control that triggered your event handler. In this case , it's the clicked button. Simply look at the content (or a specific name) of the caller and operate on the correct controls. This is an example in C# WPF.

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button clickedButton = sender as Button;

        switch(clickedButton.Content.ToString())
        {
            case "Button1":
                textbox1.Text = "10";
                checkbox1.IsChecked = true;                                        
                break;
            case "Button2":
                textbox2.Text = "20";
                checkbox2.IsChecked = true;
                break;
            case "Button3":
                textbox3.Text = "30";
                checkbox3.IsChecked = true;                    
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Create new controls every time the button is clicked?